# Deployment and handle routing of new service into Kubernetes with zero downtime having same destination

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, devops

I am new in Kubernetes. I am working on one thing that I have one old spring boot service deployed on Kubernetes and its working fine. Now I have created new spring boot service having same destination and have deployed but how can I route the traffic to new service with ZERO downtime. I have set the weightage to 0 in old virtual service and 100 to new one but it is not working.
Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mention "service" but I am not sure if you mean an actual kubernetes Service or a Deployment. A Kubernetes Deployment that has the RollingUpdate strategy set will do this out of the box for you. It works like this: `kubectl apply -f my-springboot-deployment.yaml`. Now go and change something (for example update the image you want to deploy). Run `kubectl apply -f my-springboot-deployment.yaml` again. Kubernets will deploy a new Pod with the new image, wait for it to be ready, then tear the old one down